# Serializing EuiSearchBar Query object to localStorage

Tags: local-storage, eui

The [EUI library](https://eui.elastic.co) has a nice ElasticSearch-like `<EuiSearchBar>` React component with a `query` property.  What is the right way to store/restore that query in the `localStorage`, so that the app restores last state properly?

I tried storing it as a string `EuiSearchBar.Query.toESQueryString(query)` and also tried to `JSON.stringify(EuiSearchBar.Query.toESQuery(query))`, but both methods had errors parsing the `defaultQuery={query}` parameter.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to answer this question without a code example.

The `query` prop of EuiSearchBar seems to be the way to get the query in string format.

From the docs on https://elastic.github.io/eui/#/forms/search-bar:

query: Sets the query on the search bar. Should only be used when the query is controlled and managed outside of the search bar itself

That's a normal string: you should be able to store it without explicitly using `JSON.stringify()`

But the mentioned `toES***` calls will give you an object. My educated guess why the JSON.stringify doesn`t work is stuff like dates in the ES Query data structure.